# Accessing Outlook with Exchange webservices: authentication error 401

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

When accessing outlook with the help of Exchange webservices, I get an authentication error 401.

Following is my code to connect to Outlook:

```
public static void usingEWS(){
              try {
                     System.out.println("***********************************************");

                     //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Users\\vermad\\Downloads\\Softz\\jssecacerts");
                     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\Softz\\jssecacerts");

                     ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("xyz@domain.com","password","domain.com");
                  service.setCredentials(credentials);
                  service.setUrl(new URI("https://vabcxdp/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));

           ItemView view = new ItemView (5);
           //System.out.println(service.getCredentials());
           //System.out.println("2");
//getting error here 
           FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);

           for(Item item : findResults.getItems()){
             item.load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent));
             System.out.println("id==========" + item.getId());
             System.out.println("sub==========" + item.getSubject());
             System.out.println("sub==========" + item.getMimeContent());
             }

        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise and on-spot. I also fixed some mis-types and indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem by using system username instead of user name example:amukati instead of username:amukati@xyz.com